# What is the most efficient way to farm enderpearls?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, xbox-one

I need several enderpearls to create Eye of Enders for portal I found (to open the end portal).  However, I am having a hard time farming endermen due to them being scarce and the drop rate of enderpearls.

Is there an efficient way to farm enderpearls?

Comment: If you can't go to the end build a general mob farm but make certain it's 3 air blocks high and avoid water. Make certain if dropping them you make the drop far. I did this in an LP of mine, not fastest but better than just waiting until you see one. Also if you hand kill them in the wild, a) duck under a 2 high with block over you space and b) only attack their feet or c) wear a pumpkin and also do b.

Answer (score 3):

This largely depends upon your definition of farming.  If by farming you mean "run around killing enough Endermen to get the pearls I need to get to The End (which is where you really want to build a true enderpearl farm) then you should just look at this question:

[How do I make Endermen spawn more frequently?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51300/how-do-i-make-endermen-spawn-more-)

If you mean, how do I build an overworld mob farm that will get me lots of endermen, then @Ydobonebi's comment is a reasonable one.